# How to transfer data from one request to another request

Tags: java, spring, rest, redirect, spring-restcontroller

I have a RestController in which the request is sent by the post method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/params", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public OneObject getParams(@RequestBody NeededObject neededObject) {
    // logics
}
```

After the server processes this request.
Comes the answer to callback endpoint.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public DifferentObject callback(@RequestBody OtherObject otherObject) {
    // processing the response otherObject and if the success
    // needs to redirect the request to another endpoint
    // with the parameters of the first query,
    // transfer to @RequestBody NeededObject neededObject
}
```

How can I implement this?

The first two endpoints are on the same controller, and I need to redirect it to another controller (Controller below).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/need", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public OneDto create(@RequestBody NeededObject neededObject) {
    // logics
}
```

I'm trying something (the code below), but I do not know if it's a good way.

And I do not know where to get the response to inserting it when include.

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/need");
requestDispatcher.include(request, response);
```

Thank you for your help.